# There is already an object named 'tbltable1' in the database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, select-into

I am trying to insert data from one table to another with same structure,

```
select * into tbltable1 from tbltable1_Link
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
There is already an object named 'tbltable1' in the database.
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [`SELECT INTO`](http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_select_into.asp) statement creates a new table of the name you provide and populates it with the results of the SELECT statement.

I think you should be using `INSERT INTO` since the table already exists. If your purpose is in fact to populate a temporary table, then you should provide a table name that does not already exist in the database.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190750.aspx) for more information on this.

Answer (score 2):

If you are confident that `tbltable1` is not required, you can drop the table first.

You may also want to consider using temporary tables...

```
Select * into ##MyTemporaryTable FROM tblTable1_Link
```

You can then use the temporary table in this session. (Ending the session should drop the temporary table automatically, if I remember correctly.  It's been a while since I've worked with SQL Server).