# Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

In the SQL Server, I am trying to insert values from one table to another by using the below query:

```
delete from tblTable1

insert into tblTable1 select * from tblTable1_Link
```

I am getting the following error:

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

I am sure that both the tables have the same structure, same column names and same data types.

Comment: One more possibility is that the DB collation on your TEMP DB and the DB you are inserting into do not match.

Comment: Isn't this highly flaggable for not posting the schemas of the tables? "I am sure" is not sufficient: we've all been in enough situations where we can't see the wood for the trees to know that our own certainty can be woefully incorrect, and it takes posting a proper volume of information about the problem for someone else to point out the obvious thing we're missing.

Comment: You should also have a look at all triggers. You will get the exact same message if you have a badly written trigger inserting into something like an audit table.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

They don't have the same structure... I can guarantee they are different

I know you've already created it... [There is already an object named ‘tbltable1’ in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152811/there-is-already-an-object-named-tbltable1-in-the-database)

What you may want is this (which also fixes your other issue):

```
Drop table tblTable1

select * into tblTable1 from tblTable1_Link
```

Answer (score 31):

I want to also mention that if you have something like

```
insert into blah
       select * from blah2
```

and blah and blah2 are identical keep in mind that a computed column will throw this same error...

I just realized that when the above failed and I tried

```
insert into blah (cola, colb, colc)
       select cola, colb, colc from blah2
```

In my example it was fullname field (computed from first and last, etc)

Comment: Worked for me. My problem wasn't inserting without explicitly stating the column names, but when I tried to join two tables that weren't created as such. Once I added the column names, my join worked. Must have been that computed column that was monkeying things up!

Comment: Thank you for the computed column issue I can confirm this is true. I had a table with the exact same number of columns in the same order. The only difference is that the source table uses a computed column.

Comment: I think I've just hit this using SELECT INTO and adding two ROW_NUMBER() columns (partitioned differently).  Its coming from a table value function too :/

Answer (score 23):

for inserts it is always better to specify the column names see the following

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        Val1 VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '1'
```

works fine, changing the table def to causes the error

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        Val1 VARCHAR(MAX),
        Val2 VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '1'
```

> Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
>   Insert Error: Column name or number of
>   supplied values does not match table
>   definition.

But changing the above to

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        Val1 VARCHAR(MAX),
        Val2 VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @Table (Val1)  SELECT '1'
```

works. You need to be more specific with the columns specified

supply the structures and we can have a look

Answer (score 13):

The problem is that you are trying to insert data into the database without using columns. SQL server gives you that error message.

Error: `insert into users values('1', '2','3')` - this works fine as long you only have 3 columns

If you have 4 columns but only want to insert into 3 of them

Correct: `insert into users (firstName,lastName,city) values ('Tom', 'Jones', 'Miami')`

Answer (score 8):

Beware of triggers. Maybe the issue is with some operation in the trigger for inserted rows.

Comment: Thank you for this! This error appeared a few hours after a production deployment on features we hadn't even touched. So, I asked the database admin about any new triggers...

Answer (score 2):

Dropping the table was not an option for me, since I'm keeping a running log.  If every time I needed to insert I had to drop, the table would be meaningless.

My error was because I had a couple columns in the create table statement that were products of other columns, changing these fixed my problem.  eg

```
create table foo (
field1 as int
,field2 as int
,field12 as field1 + field2 )

create table copyOfFoo (
field1 as int
,field2 as int
,field12 as field1 + field2)  --this is the problem, should just be 'as int'

insert into copyOfFoo
SELECT * FROM foo
```

Answer (score 2):

some sources for this issues are as below

1- Identity column ,

2- Calculated Column

3- different structure

so check those 3 , i found my issue was the second one ,

Answer (score 1):

The computed columns make the problem. 
Do not use `SELECT *`. You must specify each fields after SELECT except computed fields

Answer (score 1):

The problem I had that caused this error was that I was trying to insert null values into a NOT NULL column.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and the way I worked around it is probably not the best but it is working now.

It involves creating a linked server and using dynamic sql - not the best, but if anyone can suggest something better, please comment/answer.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)


DECLARE @DB_SPACE TABLE (
[DatabaseName] NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
[FILEID] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[FILE_SIZE_MB] INT NOT NULL DEFAULT (0),
[SPACE_USED_MB] INT NULL DEFAULT (0),
[FREE_SPACE_MB] INT NULL DEFAULT (0),
[LOGICALNAME] SYSNAME NOT NULL,
[DRIVE] NCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
[FILENAME] NVARCHAR(260) NOT NULL,
[FILE_TYPE] NVARCHAR(260) NOT NULL,
[THE_AUTOGROWTH_IN_KB] INT NOT NULL DEFAULT(0)
,filegroup VARCHAR(128)
,maxsize VARCHAR(25)

PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([DatabaseName] ,[FILEID] )
)  


SELECT @SQL ='SELECT [DatabaseName],
        [FILEID],
        [FILE_SIZE_MB],
        [SPACE_USED_MB],
        [FREE_SPACE_MB],
        [LOGICALNAME],
        [DRIVE],
        [FILENAME],
        [FILE_TYPE],
        [THE_AUTOGROWTH_IN_KB]
        ,filegroup
        ,maxsize FROM OPENQUERY('+ QUOTENAME('THE_MONITOR') + ','''+ ' EXEC MASTER.DBO.monitoring_database_details '  +''')'
exec sp_executesql @sql


      INSERT INTO @DB_SPACE(
                            [DatabaseName],
                            [FILEID],
                            [FILE_SIZE_MB],
                            [SPACE_USED_MB],
                            [FREE_SPACE_MB],
                            [LOGICALNAME],
                            [DRIVE],
                            [FILENAME],
                            [FILE_TYPE],
                            THE_AUTOGROWTH_IN_KB,
                            [filegroup],
                            maxsize
                          )

      EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
```

This is working for me now.
I can guarantee the number of columns and type of columns returned by the stored procedure are the same as in this table, simply because I return the same table from the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

For me the culprit is int value assigned to salary

Insert into Employees(ID,FirstName,LastName,Gender,Salary) values(3,'Canada', 'pa', 'm',15,000)

in salary column When we assign 15,000 the compiler understand 15 and 000.

This correction works fine for me.
Insert into Employees(ID,FirstName,LastName,Gender,Salary) values(4,'US', 'sam', 'm',15000)

Answer (score 0):

Check your `id`. Is it Identity? If it is then make sure it is declared as `ID not null Identity(1,1)`

And before creating your table , `Drop table` and then `create table`.

Answer (score 0):

**Update to SQL server 2016/2017/…**
We have some stored procedures in place to import and export databases.
In the sp we use (amongst other things) RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK where we create a 
table "#restoretemp" for the restore from file.

With SQL server 2016, MS has added a field **SnapshotURL nvarchar(360)** (restore url Azure) what has caused the error message.
After I have enhanced the additional field, the restore has worked again.
**Code snipped (see last field):**

```
 SET @query = 'RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = ' + QUOTENAME(@BackupFile , '''')
CREATE TABLE #restoretemp
(
LogicalName nvarchar(128)
,PhysicalName nvarchar(128)
,[Type] char(1)
,FileGroupName nvarchar(128)
,[Size] numeric(20,0)
,[MaxSize] numeric(20,0)
,FileID bigint
,CreateLSN numeric(25,0)
,DropLSN numeric(25,0) NULL
,UniqueID uniqueidentifier
,ReadOnlyLSN numeric(25,0)
,ReadWriteLSN numeric(25,0)
,BackupSizeInByte bigint
,SourceBlockSize int
,FilegroupID int
,LogGroupGUID uniqueidentifier NULL
,DifferentialBaseLSN numeric(25,0)
,DifferentialbaseGUID uniqueidentifier
,IsReadOnly bit
,IsPresent bit
,TDEThumbprint varbinary(32)
-- Added field 01.10.2018 needed from SQL Server 2016 (Azure URL)
,SnapshotURL nvarchar(360)
)

INSERT #restoretemp EXEC (@query)
SET @errorstat = @@ERROR
if @errorstat <> 0 
Begin
if @Rueckgabe = 0 SET @Rueckgabe = 6
End
Print @Rueckgabe
```

Comment: I know this answer wasn't what the original person asked for but it did help me out.  So thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had:

```
insert into table1 one
select * from same_schema_as_table1 same_schema
left join...
```

and I had to change `select *` to `select same_schema.*`.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing column name after TableName in insert query:

```
INSERT INTO TableName**(Col_1,Col_2,Col_3)** VALUES(val_1,val_2,val_3)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that the SP I was executing returned two result sets, and only the second result set was matching the table definition.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst the other answers work fine for insert purposes, you can also just run the following:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..@table) IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE @table. 
Then go back and rerun 

DECLARE @Table TABLE(        
 Val1 VARCHAR(MAX),
 Val2 VARCHAR(MAX) )  
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '1' .
```

It should work.

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score -1):

I just solved the same problem after spending quite some time digging up the root cause. The number of input parameters in C# code matched the number of input parameters in the stored procedure. The number of output parameters of the stored procedure also matched the number of variables in the receiving class of the C# code. Every output column name of the stored procedure also matched exactly one variable name of the receiving class.

Finally, after consulting my boss, the problem was solved after I executed the `alter procedure` command to the stored procedure after doing absolutely nothing. She encountered the same problem before and also did this to solve it.

Pretty weird SQL Server related stuff!