# Strange issue between sql server 2005 (32x) and sql server 2008 (64x) linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, linked-server

I have successfully created linked server between 2005 and 2008 version. We changed a table schema on 2008 and re ordered the table columns. We also did the same on 2005 server.

If we query both table in their own database then schema looks fine however

when I do

SELECT * FROM  and Select * from  then it is showing me old schema for 2008 table. Due to this my join and inserts are failing. Error "insert failed due to table column mismatch"

We restarted both the machines still not luck

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found answer on stack overflow it self :D

[Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152932/column-name-or-number-of-supplied-values-does-not-match-table-definition)

Do drop #table and then select * INTO